# Why does my Android string display in all caps in my app?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I want to display Vo for initial velocity, and it displays fine in MOST places, but on all of my circle buttons, it displays in all caps, so it looks like "VO" instead of "Vo".

Is there a way to fix this?  Is it a weird button interaction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buttons are all-caps by default since Android 5.0. If you want to disable this, you may have to specify [`android:textAllCaps="false"`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textAllCaps) on your Buttons.

Comment: Well I'll be damned.  Thanks for the wicked fast response!